# TeamFoundationServer.[Extended]Client: Get my subscriptions via

Tags: c#

I want to access and change my TFS notifications through the [.NET client libraries for VSTS (and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries). For instance I am able to get changeset details for a given changeset number as follows:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://..."));
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
var vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var changeset = vcs.GetChangeset(378418);
```

I was hoping to be able to access my notifications in the same manor

```
var ns = tpc.GetService<NotificationSubscription>();
```

but `ns` is null, so probably that's not the way to go. What do I have to do instead?

Comment: Post it as a reply instead of a comment and I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TFS rest api to [update an existing Notification subscription](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/notification/subscriptions#update):

```
PATCH http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/notification/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}?api-version=3.2-preview

Content-Type: application/json

{
 ...
}
```

I've tested on my side, it's working.

Rest Api is more simplerthan SOAP api. To use SOAP api, you would need to use `GetService<IEventService>`, check this case for more information: [TFS 2015 Alert API: Create an alert for Team or TFS Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528850/tfs-2015-alert-api-create-an-alert-for-team-or-tfs-group).

Comment: I have the feeling, that working with notifications is only possible via the REST API. Is this true?

Comment: Rest Api is more simplerthan SOAP api. To use SOAP api, you would need to use `GetService<IEventService>`, check this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528850/tfs-2015-alert-api-create-an-alert-for-team-or-tfs-group